# Composer Update issue Laravel 5

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

When i run the update command of composer i get the following exception at the end of update process.

[image]

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this file:

```
/vendor/compiled.php
```

and run `composer update` again.